# Difference between starting a command using init.d script and service start

Tags: linux, shell, command

I need to understand the difference between starting a command using `init.d` script and `service start`.

For example what is the difference between

`/etc/init.d/nginx start` and `service nginx start`.

Answer (score 9):

They do the same thing except `service` runs the script in a controlled environment. From the [service(8) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/service):

> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> service  runs  a  System  V init script in as predictable environment
>   as possible, removing most environment variables and with current
>   working directory set to `/`.
>
> #### ENVIRONMENT
>
> `LANG`, `TERM`
>           The only environment variables passed to the init scripts.

Answer (score 9):

**Furthermore:**

Calling **/etc/init.d/*** scripts directly is deprecated by facts because:

On latest Debian/Ubuntu distro ( and derived ), sysvinit ( which was default init system ) has been replaced by either upstart or systemd. Thus, if one of the service is managed using either an usptart job or systemd unit configuration file, calling **/etc/init.d/*** will be a **NOOP** in sense that the script will exit without further information.

Instead, users must use the `service` command to *start/stop/restart* services. The `service` command is a wrapper which will invoke the right script, in as predictable environment as possible, whatever the init system in use ( sysinit, upstart or systemd ).