# Debian 8 openvpn init script ignoring config file

Tags: debian, init, openvpn

when I run openvpn with 'openvpn server.conf' from '/etc/openvpn' everything works fine. But when i run '/etc/init.d/openvpn start' or '/etc/init.d/openvpn start server' or '/etc/init.d/openvpn start server.conf' the server.conf configfile is ignored.
Why?

Hope someone can help me.

Regards.

Comment: Better to ask on http://serverfault.com.

Comment: @RoryJaffe: Thank you for your notice, I didn't know that. Will ask next question on serverfault.com. NOT 'Thank you' four your minus vote ;) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. 
Instead of using `/etc/init.d/openvpn restart` you can use

`service openvpn restart` or

`systemctl restart openvpn.service`

to start/stop/restart/reload services.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28930361/6217547 led me to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is systemd status (Debian 8 is running with systemd if I'm correct).

So you can do: **systemctl status openvpn** and check the output.

1. Active: active (running)  => here it doesn't help much
2. Active: active (exited)   => it has been started properly and exited with no error, common reason could be that there is no config file found.
3. Active: failed (Result: exit-code) =>  it has been started and failed with error. THen you can do a **journalctl -xe** and check the messages.

Let us know the result of this.

Comment: Hey Florent, thank you for your answer. `systemctl status openvpn` results in: `Active: active (exited)`. Btw, i run all this commands as root. `server.conf` has root as owner:group an `rw` for owner, `r` for group.

Comment: Me again. I tested same command on my client (raspbian). `/etc/init.d/openvpn start` works fine there. `systemctl status openvpn` results in `Active: active (exited)`, too. And `ps aux | grep openvpn` results in `/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-client --status /run/openvpn/client.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.conf`. So I see, that the client.conf was found and is used. `ps aux | grep openvpn` on server side shows nothing.

Comment: Do you have mutiple config file (*.conf) in /etc/openvpn/ ?

Comment: No, i don't. Found a solution. See my answer.

Comment: Yes that was implied by my answer, I though you would have tried to play around systemctl...